# Max number of Activities!

Tags: android, performance, optimization, user-interface, design-principles

Is there any design guideline on the number of Activities an application could have? If there is a limit, what would be the ideal number of Activities that can be bundled in an Android application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is IMO no such limit, typical application would have < 10 activities (screens). Do you plan something that would be highly above this number?

Comment: Nope, I don't. I saw Romain Guy's video on UI design. In which he specified that he is angered by developers who use SO MANY activities writing applications in the Android market. That's y I asked this question. Thank u @krtek.

Comment: @krtek : Some applications require far more than 10 activities.

Comment: @Ashwin you're right, indeed. My point was, that you don't have to worry about some *Activity limit*.